# How to create a TreeMultimap from an Iterable/Collection?

Tags: java, guava

I'm trying to trim a `TreeMultimap`, and have the same structured `TreeMultimap` returned (but trimmed). For example, i have different news providers that returns unordered news. I need to sort the news by date and maintain this sort in the sorted multimap by most recent date. Then i need the ability to return the most recent X news. Per date, there may be many news.

```
TreeMultimap<Date, String> latestNews = TreeMultimap.create(Ordering.natural().reverse(), Ordering.natural());
```

Because there is no trim, or size of the `TreeMultimap`, I've managed to return an `Iterable` and limit the results with that, but how to create a new `TreeMultimap` from the `Iterable`?

Essentially, the idea is:

- create new sorted TreeMultimap
- put as many entries as there are available (
- trim to X and return the map

Also, what about different sets of data for example if I want to implement paging like features?

Here is how to return the last 5 news for example

```
Map.Entry<Date, String> lastFiveNews = Iterables.limit(latestNews.entries(), 5)
```

But how do I create a new Multimap from the result?

Easiest way would be as simple as iterating and creating a new `TreeMultimap`:

```
TreeMultimap<Date, String> lastFiveNews = TreeMultimap.create(Ordering.natural().reverse(), Ordering.natural());

for (Map.Entry<Date, String> dateStringEntry : Iterables.limit(latestNews.entries(), 5)) {
    lastFiveNews.put(dateStringEntry.getKey(), dateStringEntry.getValue());
}
latestNews.clear();
latestNews.putAll(lastFiveNews);
```

I was wondering if there is an actual utility class/constructor that can do that directly. This approach using the Iterables was the only one I could think of. There may be other approaches too.

Comment: So you have `Iterable<Map.Entry>` and you want to create a `TreeMultimap` from that? I cant find `Iterables#limit` here http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html what does it do?

Comment: Hi, this is Guava, not google-collections. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html

Comment: Ahh okay, `Iterables.limit` returns an `Iterable` so does this not break, `Map.Entry<Date, String> lastFiveNews = Iterables.limit(latestNews.entries(), 5)` Don't you want `Iterable<Map.Entry>`?

Comment: Actually I need new `TreeMultimap` object to return with the result from the `Iterables`. It would be easy to simply iterate it and use put on the `TreeMultimap` object. I was wondering if there is an actual utility class/constructor that can do that directly. This approach using the `Iterables` was the only one I found. There may be other solutions

Comment: @Tony: [Guava contains a strictly compatible superset of the old, deprecated Google Collections Library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries). It's simply the new Google Collections.

Comment: @maaartinus I know, but I was not asking that. How is that relevant?

Comment: That small loop to add the entries seems fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're already doing it is exactly what you should do.

You may be interested in the discussion on https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=320, which is related. (This seems like an actual valid use case for those methods, actually.)